# Efficient evaluation of a function at every cell of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, vectorization

Given NumPy array `A`, what is the fastest/most efficient way to apply the *same* function `f()` to *every* cell?

I assign to `A(i,j)` by `f(A(i,j))`. Function `f()` doesn't have binary output, so masking operations won't help. Is double loop iteration through every cell the optimal solution?

Comment: [numpy.apply_over_axes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy.apply_over_axes)

Answer (score 164):

You could just [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) the function and then apply it directly to a Numpy array each time you need it:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x * x + 3 * x - 2 if x > 0 else x * 5 + 8

f = np.vectorize(f)  # or use a different name if you want to keep the original f

result_array = f(A)  # if A is your Numpy array
```

It's probably better to specify an explicit output type directly when vectorizing:

```
f = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.float])
```

Comment: I am afraid that the vectorized function cannot be faster than the "manual" double loop iteration and assignment through all the array elements. Especially, because it stores the result to a **newly** created variable (and not directly to the initial input). Thanks a lot for your reply though:)

Comment: @Peter: Ah, now I see that you have mentioned assigning the result back to the former array in your original question. I'm sorry I missed that when first reading it. Yeah, in that case the double loop must be faster. But have you also tried a single loop on the flattened view of the array? That might be _slightly_ faster, since you save a little loop overhead and Numpy needs to do one less multiplication and addition (for calculating the data offset) at each iteration. Plus it works for arbitrarily dimensioned arrays. Might be slower on very small arrays, tho.

Comment: Notice the warning given in the `vectorize` function description: *The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.* So this will very likely not speed up the process at all.

Comment: Pay attention to how `vectorize` determines the return type.  That has produced bugs.  `frompyfunc` is a bit faster, but returns a dtype object array.  Both feed scalars, not rows or columns.

Comment: @blubberdiblub `np.vectorize(f)(np.array([]))` raises `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Specifying `otypes` as mentioned in the answer should take care of that IndexError.

Comment: @Gabriel Just throwing `np.vectorize` on my function (which utilizes RK45) gives me a speed up of a factor of ~ 20.

Answer (score 6):

A similar question is: [Mapping a NumPy array in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824122/mapping-a-numpy-array-in-place).
If you can find a [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#available-ufuncs) for your f(), then you should use the out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with numbers and `f(A(i,j)) = f(A(j,i))`, you could use [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) defining f as a distance between `A(i)` and `A(j)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a better solution. The idea to change the function to python universal function (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)), which can exercise parallel computation under the hood.

One can write his own customised `ufunc` in C, which surely is more efficient, or by invoking `np.frompyfunc`, which is built-in factory method. After testing, this is more efficient than `np.vectorize`:

```py
f = lambda x, y: x * y
f_arr = np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1)
vf = np.vectorize(f)
arr = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000)

%timeit f_arr(arr, arr) # 307ms
%timeit f_arr(arr, arr) # 450ms
```

I have also tested larger samples, and the improvement is proportional. For comparison of performances of other methods, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

When the 2d-array (or nd-array) is C- or F-contiguous, then this task of mapping a function onto a 2d-array is practically the same as the task of mapping a function onto a 1d-array - we just have to view it that way, e.g. via [`np.ravel(A,'K')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel).

Possible solution for 1d-array have been discussed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54312134/5769463).

However, when the memory of the 2d-array isn't contiguous, then the situation a little bit more complicated, because one would like to avoid possible cache misses if axis are handled in wrong order.

Numpy has already a machinery in place to process axes in the best possible order. One possibility to use this machinery is `np.vectorize`. However, numpy's documentation on [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html?highlight=vectorize#numpy.vectorize) states that it is "provided primarily for convenience, not for performance" - a slow python function stays a slow python function with the whole associated overhead! Another issue is its huge memory-consumption - see for example this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253839/why-vectorize-is-outperformed-by-frompyfunc).

When one wants to have a performance of a C-function but to use numpy's machinery, a good solution is to use numba for creation of ufuncs, for example:

```
# runtime generated C-function as ufunc
import numba as nb
@nb.vectorize(target="cpu")
def nb_vf(x):
    return x+2*x*x+4*x*x*x
```

It easily beats `np.vectorize` but also when the same function would be performed as numpy-array multiplication/addition, i.e.

```
# numpy-functionality
def f(x):
    return x+2*x*x+4*x*x*x

# python-function as ufunc
import numpy as np
vf=np.vectorize(f)
vf.__name__="vf"
```

See appendix of this answer for time-measurement-code:

[image]

Numba's version (green) is about 100 times faster than the python-function (i.e. `np.vectorize`), which is not surprising. But it is also about 10 times faster than the numpy-functionality, because numbas version doesn't need intermediate arrays and thus uses cache more efficiently.

---

While numba's ufunc approach is a good trade-off between usability and performance, it is still not the best we can do. Yet there is no silver bullet or an approach best for any task - one has to understand what are the limitation and how they can be mitigated.

For example, for transcendental functions (e.g. `exp`, `sin`, `cos`) numba doesn't provide any advantages over numpy's `np.exp` (there are no temporary arrays created - the main source of the speed-up). However, my Anaconda installation utilizes Intel's VML for vectors [bigger than 8192](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9129#issuecomment-380284038) - it just cannot do it if memory is not contiguous. So it might be better to copy the elements to a contiguous memory in order to be able to use Intel's VML:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.vectorize(target="cpu")
def nb_vexp(x):
    return np.exp(x)

def np_copy_exp(x):
    copy = np.ravel(x, 'K')
    return np.exp(copy).reshape(x.shape)
```

For the fairness of the comparison, I have switched off VML's parallelization (see code in the appendix):

[image]

As one can see, once VML kicks in, the overhead of copying is more than compensated. Yet once data becomes too big for L3 cache, the advantage is minimal as task becomes once again memory-bandwidth-bound.

On the other hand, numba could use Intel's SVML as well, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56939240/5769463):

```
from llvmlite import binding
# set before import
binding.set_option('SVML', '-vector-library=SVML')

import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize(target="cpu")
def nb_vexp_svml(x):
    return np.exp(x)
```

and using VML with parallelization yields:

[image]

numba's version has less overhead, but for some sizes VML beats SVML even despite of the additional copying overhead - which isn't a bit surprise as numba's ufuncs aren't parallelized.

---

Listings:

A. comparison of polynomial function:

```
import perfplot
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n,n)[::2,::2],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0,12)],
    kernels=[
        f,
        vf, 
        nb_vf
        ],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(x)'
    )
```

B. comparison of `exp`:

```
import perfplot
import numexpr as ne # using ne is the easiest way to set vml_num_threads
ne.set_vml_num_threads(1)
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n,n)[::2,::2],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0,12)],
    kernels=[
        nb_vexp, 
        np.exp,
        np_copy_exp,
        ],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(x)',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

All above answers compares well, but if you need to use custom function for mapping, and you have `numpy.ndarray`, and you need to retain the shape of array.

I have compare just two, but it will retain the shape of `ndarray`. I have used the array with 1 million entries for comparison. Here I use square function. I am presenting the general case for n dimensional array. For two dimensional just make `iter` for 2D.

```py
import numpy, time

def A(e):
    return e * e

def timeit():
    y = numpy.arange(1000000)
    now = time.time()
    numpy.array([A(x) for x in y.reshape(-1)]).reshape(y.shape)        
    print(time.time() - now)
    now = time.time()
    numpy.fromiter((A(x) for x in y.reshape(-1)), y.dtype).reshape(y.shape)
    print(time.time() - now)
    now = time.time()
    numpy.square(y)  
    print(time.time() - now)
```

**Output**

```
>>> timeit()
1.162431240081787    # list comprehension and then building numpy array
1.0775556564331055   # from numpy.fromiter
0.002948284149169922 # using inbuilt function
```

here you can clearly see `numpy.fromiter` user square function, use any of your choice. If you function is dependent on `i, j`  that is indices of array, iterate on size of array like `for ind in range(arr.size)`,  use `numpy.unravel_index` to get `i, j, ..` based on your 1D index and shape of array [numpy.unravel_index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html?highlight=unravel%20index#numpy.unravel_index)

This answers is inspired by my answer on other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61134821/8630792)