# place random numbers for nan values numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, random, numpy

I have a numpy array X that has `nan` values in it.

```
X = np.array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
              [  4.,  nan,  54.],
              [ 90.,  32.,  nan],
              [ 55.,  42.,  86.]])
```

I'd like to replace all nan values with a **different** random number. I can generate the random number easily with `np.random.randn()`. I can use a mask to locate and count the nans.

```
mx = ma.masked_array(X,mask=np.isnan(X)) //locate nans
mx.mask.sum()      // count nans so I know how many random values to generate
```

My issue is I don't know how to input them in quickly and efficiently. The example I gave above is a very small dataset, but I have one that is much much larger. Therefore efficiency is key.

If I try

```
X[mx.mask] = np.random.randn() //or 
X[mx.mask]=np.random.randn(mx.mask.sum())
```

I replace each nan with the *same* random number which is not what I want or I get a broadcast error in the second example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701429/efficient-evaluation-of-a-function-at-every-cell-of-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
X[np.isnan(X)] = np.random.randn(len(X[np.isnan(X)]))
```

The above works perfectly for me. Numpy version 1.8.0.

Comment: Wow I'm a noob I must have had some typo somewhere. Will checkmark this when 10 minutes pass thanks!