# python why data type changed by def function?

Tags: python, numpy

Why num_r1(x) and num_r2(x) type numpy.ndarray, but num_r(t) is type float? How can I keep num_r(t) type as array?

```
def num_r(t):
    for x in t:
        if x>tx:
            return num_r2(x)
        else:
            return num_r1(x)
```

Thank you!

The complete example is below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
from pylab import *

#### physical parameters
c = 2.998*10**10
hp = 6.626*10**-27
hb = 1.055*10**-27
kb = 1.381*10**-16
g = 6.673*10**-8
me = 9.109*10**-28
mp = 1.673*10**-24
q = 4.803*10**-10  #gausi
sigT = 6.652*10**-25

# The evolution of the characteristic frequencies
p = 2.5
E52 = 1
epsB_r = 1
epse_r = 1

D28 = 1 
n1 = 1.0
nu15 = 1*10**(-5)
r014 = 1
g42 = 1
delt12 =1
g4 = g42*10**2.5

E0 = E52*10**52
eta = g4
N0 = E0/(g4*mp*c**2)



p_tx = 3**(1./3)*2**(4./3)*mp**(-1./3)*c**(-5./3)
tx = p_tx*n1**(-1./3)*eta**(-8./3)

p_num_r1 = 2**(11./2)*7**(-2)*mp**(5./2)*me**(-3)*pi**(-1./2)*q*p_tx**(-6)*2**30*3**18*10**12

p_nuc_r1 = 2**(-33./2)*3**(-4)*10**(-4)*me*mp**(-3./2)*c**(-2)*sigT**(-2)*pi**(-1./2)*q

p_Fmax_r1 = 2**(15./2)*3**(9./2)*10**30*p_tx**(-3./2)*10**(-56)*me*mp**(1./2)*c**3*sigT*q**(-1)*2**(1./2)*3**(-1)

p_num_r2 = 2**(11./2)*7**(-2)*mp**(5./2)*me**(-3)*pi**(-1./2)*q*p_tx**(54./35)*(2**5*3**3*10**2)**(-54./35)

p_nuc_r2 = 2**(-13./2)*3**2*pi**(-1./2)*me*mp**(-3./2)*c**(-2)*sigT**(-2)*q*p_tx**(-74./35)*(2**5*3**3*10**2)**(4./35)

p_Fmax_r2 = 2**(1./2)*3**(-1)*pi**(-1./2)*me*mp**(1./2)*c**3*sigT*q**(-1)*10**(-56)



num_r1 = lambda t : p_num_r1*eta**18*((p-2)/(p-1))**2*epse_r**2*epsB_r**(1./2)*n1**(5./2)*t**6*E52**(-2)

nuc_r1 = lambda t : p_nuc_r1*eta**(-4)*epsB**(-3./2)*n1**(-3./2)*t**(-2)

Fmax_r1 = lambda t : p_Fmax_r1*N0**t**(3./2)*n1*eta**6*E52**(-1./2)*D28**(-2)*epsB_r**(1./2)

num_r2 = lambda t : p_num_r2*((p-2)/(p-1))**2*n1**(-74./35)*n1**(74./105)*eta**(592./105)*E52**(-74./105)

nuc_r2 = lambda t : p_nuc_r2*eta**(172./105)*t**(4./35)*n1**(-167./210)*epsB_r**(-3./2)

Fmax_r2 = lambda t : N0*eta**(62./105)*n1**(37./210)*epsB_r**(1./2)*t**(-34./35)*D28**(-2)

def fspe(t,u):
  if num_r(t)<nuc_r(t):
    return np.where(u<num_r(t),(u/num_r(t))**(1./3)*Fmax_r(t),np.where(u<nuc_r(t),(u/num_r(t))**(-(p-1.)/2)*Fmax_r(t),(u/nuc_r(t))**(-p/2)*(nuc_r(t)/num_r(t))**(-(p-1.)/2)*Fmax_r(t)))
  else:
    return np.where(u<nuc_r(t),(u/nuc_r(t))**(1./3)*Fmax_r(t),np.where(u<num_r(t),(u/nuc_r(t))**(-1./2)*Fmax_r(t),(u/num_r(t))**(-p/2)*(num_r(t)/nuc_r(t))**(-1.2)*Fmax_r(t)))


def num_r(t):
 for x in t:
  if x>tx:
    return num_r2(x)
  else:
    return num_r1(x)
def nuc_r(t):
 for x in t:
  if t>tx:
    return nuc_r2(x)
  else:
    return nuc_r1(x)
def Fmax_r(t):
 for x in t:
  if t>tx:
    return Fmax_r2(x)
  else:
    return Fmax_r1(x)


i= np.arange(-4,6,0.1)
t = 10**i
dnum   = [math.log10(mmm) for mmm in num_r(t)]
dnuc   = [math.log10(j) for j in nuc_r(t)]
nu_obs = [math.log(2.4*10**17,10) for a in i]
plt.figure('God Bless: Observable Limit')
plt.title(r'$\nu_{obs}$ and $\nu_c$ and $\nu_m$''\nComparation')
plt.xlabel('Time: log t')
plt.ylabel(r'log $\nu$')
plt.axvline(math.log10(tx))
plt.plot(i,nu_obs,'.',label=r'$\nu_{obs}$')
plt.plot(i,dnum,'D',label=r'$\nu_m$')
plt.plot(i,dnuc,'s',label=r'$\nu_c$')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("nu_obs.eps", dpi=120,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

But thereś a Error

```
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-250-c008d4ed7571> in <module>()
     95     i= np.arange(-4,6,0.1)
     96     t = 10**i
--->     97     dnum   = [math.log10(mmm) for mmm in num_r(t)]
```

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: ok, I 'd modify the question, to provide the complete example. wait me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your function as:

```
def num_r_(x):
  if x > tx:
      return num_r2(x)
  else:
      return num_r1(x)
```

And then pass it through `np.vectorize` to lift it from `float` to `float` to `np.array` to `np.array`

```
num_r = np.vectorize(num_r_)
```

From [Efficient evaluation of a function at every cell of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701429/efficient-evaluation-of-a-function-at-every-cell-of-a-numpy-array)

And then when you use it in:

```
dnum = [math.log10(mmm) for mmm in num_r(t)]
```

You should rather do:

```
dnum = np.log10(num_r(t))
```

That is to say don't use the functions from the `math` module. Use those from the `np` module as they can take `np.array` as well as float.

As:

```
i = np.arange(-4,6,0.1)
t = 10**i
```

results in `t` being a `np.array`

Answer (score 1):

So `i` is an array (`arange`); so is `t` (a math expression of `i`).

```
def num_r(t):
 for x in t:
  if x>tx:
    return num_r2(x)
  else:
    return num_r1(x)
```

You iterate on `t`.  `x` is an element of `t`.  You test it and pass it through `num_r2` or `num_r1`, and return **immediately**.  So only the 1st element `t` is being processed. Thus the error - `num_r` returns one value, not an array.

You need to write `num_r` in a way that processes all the values of `t`, not just the first.  A simple, crude way is

```
def num_r(t):
    result = []
    for x in t:
       if x>tx:
          value = num_r2(x)
       else:
          value = num_r1(x)
       result.append(value)
    # result = np.array(result)
    return result
```

Now `num_r` should return a list the same length as `t`, and can be use in the list comprehension

```
[math.log10(mmm) for mmm in num_r(t)]
```

`num_r` could be written as a list comprehension:

```
[(num_r2(x) if x>tx else num_r1(x)) for x in t]
```

You could have it return an array instead of a list, but as long as you are using it in the list comprehension, there's no need.  A list is just fine.

If it did return an array, then you could replace the list comprehension with a numpy log operation, e.g.

```
np.log10(num_r(t))
```

If `num_r1` and `num_r2` are written so they can take an array (looks off hand like they are, but I haven't tested), you could write

```
def num_r(t):
     ind = t>tx
     result = np.zeros_like(t)
     result[ind] = num_r2(t[ind])
     result[~ind] = num_r1(t[~ind])
     return result
```

The idea is to find a mask of a values in `t` that are `>tx`, and pass all those through `num_r2` at once; similarly for `num_r1`; and collect the values in the correct slots of `result`.  The result is an array that can be passed to `np.log10`.  This should be quite a bit faster than iterating on `t`, or using `np.vectorize`.

There may be some errors in my suggestions, since I did not test them in an script or interpreter.  But the underlying ideas should be correct and set you on the right path.

Comment: While not actually faster in this case, `np.where(t>tx, num_r2(t), num_r1(t))` is a more concise way to express this.

Comment: Yes `where` should work.  But practice with basic masked indexing is also desirable.

Comment: I really appreciate it ! Thanks for your help, though some other Errors occur, I believe your method is useful. I'd like to study the detail from your illustrations. Thank you again!  God Bless You!