# How can I map python callable over numpy array in both elegant and efficient way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

The canonical approach (use of `np.vectorize()`) is not working in case of empty array - it ends with `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x + 1
...
>>> F = np.vectorize(f)
>>> F(np.array([]))
[Traceback removed]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

At the moment I use

```
>>> np.array([f(x) for x in X])
```

but I am looking for more elegant solution (and efficient). In Python 2 I may go with

```
>>> np.array(map(f, X))
```

but it fails in Python 3.

[EDIT]

The question has no answer in [Efficient evaluation of a function at every cell of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701429/efficient-evaluation-of-a-function-at-every-cell-of-a-numpy-array) since:

- `vectorise` fails,
- the OP requested solution working in place: `A(i, j) := f(A(i, j))`.

Comment: `np.array(list(map(f, X)))`

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis(f, -1, arr)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: works for me, I would like to upvote (and even accept) your answer but the question has been closed.

Comment: @abukaj yes, well it *is a duplicate*, however, the highest voted answer suggests using `np.vectorize`, which I personally consider not the right way to go about it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, I disagree since OP is looking for something working in place while I need a map _function_ (without side effects altering the array)

Comment: Though not well versed in NumPy I'm re-opening this based on your claim that `vectorize` fails.

Comment: Does your `f` expect scalar values? And what are the dimensions of `X`?

Comment: @hpaulj No, `f` is an arbitrary callable, in the particular case `operator.getattr('name')`. `X` is 1D, it would be nice (but not required) if the solution worked also for `list`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.vectorize` should work with an `f` that expects a scalar.  But, it does have a problem with an empty input:

```
In [364]: def f(x):
     ...:     return 2*x
     ...: 
In [365]: fv = np.vectorize(f)
In [366]: fv(np.array([1,2,3]))
Out[366]: array([2, 4, 6])
In [367]: fv(np.array([]))
....
ValueError: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set
```

My error is different than yours, but maybe that's a version issue.  `vectorize`, without `otypes` makes a test calculation to determine the return type.  If the input is empty, that gives a problem.  The fix is to specify the `otypes`.

```
In [368]: fv1 = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[int])
In [369]: fv1(np.array([]))
Out[369]: array([], dtype=int32)
```

`vectorize` uses `np.frompyfunc`; the main difference is that `frompyfunc` returns an object array.  Both have the big advantage that they take care of broadcasting.  The input can be an array of any shape and dimension.  Even better they work with multiple inputs, broadcasting them against each other.  But `vectorize` warns that it is still iterative, so doesn't promise any speed improvements.

Read the comments of the accepted answer in the linked question.

But if the array (or list) is always 1d, you don't need that extra power.  A plain Python iteration is as good as anything.  It could be `map` (or `list(map` in py3), but I prefer the clarity of list comprehensions.

```
ret = [f(x) for x in X]  # works with list or array
np.array(ret)    # if you want an array
```

---

One thing to watch out for is the `type` of the elements produced by various iteration methods

Iteration on an array produces array elements, or numpy dtypes:

```
In [387]: [type(x) for x in np.arange(3)]
Out[387]: [numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int32]
```

Iteration on a list returns the elements, what ever they are:

```
In [388]: [type(x) for x in [1,2,3]]
Out[388]: [int, int, int]
```

Iteration with `frompyfunc` produces 'scalars'

```
In [389]: ff=np.frompyfunc(type,1,1)
In [390]: ff(np.arange(3))
Out[390]: array([<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>], dtype=object)
In [391]: ff([1,2,3])
Out[391]: array([<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>], dtype=object)
In [393]: list(map(type,np.arange(3)))
Out[393]: [numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int32]
```

---

The part of `vectorize` that parses `otypes` is:

```
    if isinstance(otypes, str):
        for char in otypes:
            if char not in typecodes['All']:
                raise ValueError("Invalid otype specified: %s" % (char,))
    elif iterable(otypes):
        otypes = ''.join([_nx.dtype(x).char for x in otypes])
    elif otypes is not None:
        raise ValueError("Invalid otype specification")
    self.otypes = otypes
```

and

```
In [423]: np.typecodes['All']
Out[423]: '?bhilqpBHILQPefdgFDGSUVOMm'
```

Comment: The documentation says `otypes` can also be a string. But, I get error if I use string. You're also using a list `[int]` here. Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: I added information on `vectorize` parses `otypes`.