# Numpy vectorized 2d array operation error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to apply a vectorized function over a 2-d array in numpy row-wise, and I'm encountering `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 2], [3, 0]], dtype=float)
coeffs = np.array([1, 1], dtype=float)

np.apply_along_axis(
    np.vectorize(lambda row: 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-coeffs.dot(row)))),
    0, X
)
```

I don't totally know how to interpret this error. How am I setting an array element with a sequence?

When I test the lambda function on a single row, it works and returns a single float. Somehow it's failing within the scope of this vectorized function, which leads me to believe that either the vectorized function is wrong or I'm not using `apply_along_axis` correctly.

Is it possible to use a vectorized function in this context? If so, how? Can a vectorized function take an array or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: Why are you calling `np.vectorize` on a function that's supposed to take rows?

Comment: I ended up using the solution suggested by Divakar, but I'm interested in understanding if it's possible to use vectorize because I thought the row-wise implementation was slightly easier to interpret.

Comment: As ironic as this might sound, `np.vectorize` isn't a vectorized operation, as you seem to be asking about. From the [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) - `"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think vectorize is just an all around bad idea. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sum-reducing the second axis of `X` against the only axis of `coeffs`. So, you could simply use `np.dot(X,coeffs)` for `sum-reductions`.

Thus, a vectorized solution would be -

```
1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-X.dot(coeffs)))
```

Sample run -

```
In [227]: X = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 2], [3, 0]], dtype=float)
     ...: coeffs = np.array([1, 1], dtype=float)
     ...: 

# Using list comprehension    
In [228]: [1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-coeffs.dot(x))) for x in X]
Out[228]: [0.7310585786300049, 0.98201379003790845, 0.95257412682243336]

# Using proposed method
In [229]: 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-X.dot(coeffs)))
Out[229]: array([ 0.73105858,  0.98201379,  0.95257413])
```

The correct way to use `np.apply_along_axis` would be to drop `np.vectorize` and apply it along the second axis of `X`, i.e. every row of `X` -

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-coeffs.dot(row))), 1,X)
```

Comment: This is right, and I actually ended up doing something very similar rather than messing with vectorize. I guess I'm more interested in why the earlier code didn't work. I'm going to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

In v 1.12 `vectorize` docs says:

> By default, `pyfunc` is
>       assumed to take scalars as input and output.

In your attempt:

```
np.apply_along_axis(
    np.vectorize(lambda row: 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-coeffs.dot(row)))),
    0, X
)
```

`apply_along_axis` iterates on all axes except `0`, and feeds the resulting 1d array to its function.  So for 2d it will iterate on 1 axis, and feed the other.  `Divakar` shows it iterating on the 0 axis, and feeding rows.  So it's basically the same as the list comprehension with an array wrapper.

`apply_along_axis` makes more sense with 3d or higher inputs, where it's more fiddly to iterate on 2 axes and feed the third to your function.

Writing your lambda as a function:

```
def foo(row):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-coeffs.dot(row)))
```

Given an array (row) it returns a scalar:

```
In [768]: foo(X[0,:])
Out[768]: 0.7310585786300049
```

But given a scalar, it returns an array:

```
In [769]: foo(X[0,0])
Out[769]: array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

That explains the `sequence` error message.  `vectorize` expected your function to return a scalar, but it got an array.

### signature

In v 1.12 `vectorize` adds a `signature` parameter, which lets us feed something bigger than a scalar to the function.  I explored it in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752552/901925

Using the `signature` I get `vectorize` to work with:

```
In [784]: f = np.vectorize(foo, signature='(n)->()')
In [785]: f(X)
Out[785]: array([ 0.73105858,  0.98201379,  0.95257413])
```

the same thing as this:

```
In [787]: np.apply_along_axis(foo,1,X)
Out[787]: array([ 0.73105858,  0.98201379,  0.95257413])
```

### timings

```
In [788]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(foo,1,X)
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.8 µs per loop
In [789]: timeit f(X)
1000 loops, best of 3: 181 µs per loop
In [790]: np.array([foo(x) for x in X])
Out[790]: array([ 0.73105858,  0.98201379,  0.95257413])
In [791]: timeit np.array([foo(x) for x in X])
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.1 µs per loop
```

list comprehension is fastest, `vectorize` slowest.