# How to apply Pandas qcut or similar function to a 2D array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to discretize the columns of a 2D array into equal-sized bucket.
A simple 2D array example, which contains NaNs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
sarray = np.random.rand(500,500)
sarray[sarray>0.9] = np.nan
```

I tried using the Pandas qcut function:

```
pd.qcut(sarray, q=10, labels=False, duplicates='drop')
```

But it only support 1D arrays

```
ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional
```

I can get the results with a list comprehension:

```
[pd.qcut(sarray[:,col], q=10, labels=False, duplicates='drop') for col in range(sarray.shape[1])]
```

But this approach is not vectorizing the calculation. Is there a way with Numpy to vectorize this discretization problem (i.e. to perform the calculation on a single 2D array instead of on multiple 1D arrays)?

Comment: The `qcut` operation is somewhat costly, so I doubt that you can gain much speed with vectorization. Maybe you can parallelize the calculation over columns instead.

Comment: Ok, but how to do the parallelization?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526700/easy-parallelization-of-numpy-apply-along-axis) thread may be helpful.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, Thanks, I'll take a look!