# updating a numpy array efficiently when the conditions are two

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Suppose that you have a 1D numpy array containing elements that are either 3 or 4

for example:

```
3
4
4
4
3
3
3
```

I would like to alter this array so that if an element is 3 then it should become some number X and if the element is 4 it should become some number Y. It is guaranteed that X is different than Y. For the above array we would get:

```
X
Y
Y
Y
X
X
X
```

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
arr[arr==3]=X
arr[arr==4]=Y
```

however, what if X is 4? Then in the end  the entire array will contain just Ys.

I am trying to avoid using a for loop for performance reasons, but if it's the only way to go, I can afford following that route.

Comment: `arr==3` will just give you a boolean array. You can first get the output of `arr==3` and `arr==4` before setting the new values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the input 1D array contains only `3` or `4`, you can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), like so -

```
np.where(A==3,X,Y)
```

Sample run #1 -

```
In [55]: A
Out[55]: array([4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4])

In [56]: X = 30; Y = 40

In [57]: np.where(A==3,X,Y)
Out[57]: array([40, 30, 40, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 40, 30, 40])
```

Sample run #2 (if `X` is `4`) -

```
In [60]: A
Out[60]: array([4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4])

In [61]: X = 4; Y = 40

In [62]: np.where(A==3,X,Y)
Out[62]: array([40,  4, 40,  4,  4,  4, 40, 40, 40, 40,  4,  4, 40,  4, 40])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use for the [map function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). A way of implementing it would be:

`result = map(lambda k: X if k==3 else Y, myarray)`

You can replace `k == 3` with any function that returns a boolean like so:

`result = map(lambda k: X if myfun(k) else Y, myarray)`

You may want to consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824122/mapping-a-numpy-array-in-place), however you will not get much speed up.