# How do I set cell values in `np.array()` based on condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array and a list of valid values in that array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,0], [2,2,0], [4,1,0], [4,1,0], [3,2,0], ... ])
valid = [1,4]
```

Is there a nice pythonic way to **set all array values to zero, that are not in the list** of valid values and **do it in-place**? After this operation, the list should look like this:

```
               [[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [4,1,0], [4,1,0], [0,0,0], ... ]
```

The following creates **a copy of the array in memory, which is bad for large arrays**:

```
arr = np.vectorize(lambda x: x if x in valid else 0)(arr)
```

It bugs me, that **for now I loop over each array element and set it** to zero if it is in the `valid` list.

Edit: I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824122/mapping-a-numpy-array-in-place) suggesting there is no in-place function to achieve this. Also stop changing my whitespaces. It's easier to see the changes in `arr` whith them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.place`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.place.html) for an `in-situ` update -

```
np.place(arr,~np.in1d(arr,valid),0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: arr
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 0]])

In [67]: np.place(arr,~np.in1d(arr,valid),0)

In [68]: arr
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Along the same lines, `np.put` could also be used -

```
np.put(arr,np.where(~np.in1d(arr,valid))[0],0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [70]: arr
Out[70]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 0]])

In [71]: np.put(arr,np.where(~np.in1d(arr,valid))[0],0)

In [72]: arr
Out[72]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I suspect that would create a temporary copy as well since you reshape an array and multiply it by its original. So it fails my "in-place" requirement. You can see this by typing `arr` after the operation. It still gives you the original array with twos and threes.

Comment: You should really just make a new answer instead of editing your old one over and over. It makes discussion difficult. With `np.place(arr,~np.in1d(arr,valid),0)` the `in1d` part still creates a memory copy of the whole array, same with `np.put(arr,np.where(~np.in1d(arr,valid))[0],0)`.

Comment: @con-f-use As I understand, `~np.in1d(arr,valid)` would be a boolean array and as such would occupy less memory than a typical integer array, correct me if I am wrong here. And then it does in-situ update in `arr`, so there is no other copy involved there.

Comment: Agreed, `np.zeroes((100),dtype=bool).nbytes` < `np.zeroes((100),dtype=float).nbytes`. But my problem is that `arr` already barely fits into memory on some target systems, and even an additionally array that is 1/8 smaller than the original, might cause problems. Also it's a matter of principal ;-) However, I thank you for all your time! I'm quiet convinced there is no in-place function and the loop is unavoidable. See my edit.

Comment: @con-f-use Yeah I guess that's the trade-off you need to make there, sorry! can't help it I guess :) Or maybe do it in chunks if you prefer a middle ground!

Comment: All suggestions are 'in-place' in the sense that `arr` has the same data buffer pointer after the change.  But they do all make a mask (temporary or not) of comparable size.  To save both memory and time I think you need to use `nditer` in `cython` (or other C level coding).

Comment: If memory is in short supply for a basic operation like this, you do not have a useful computing environment - the mix of data, machine and language is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing with booleans would work too:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [4, 1, 0], [4, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0]])
>>> arr[~np.in1d(arr, valid).reshape(arr.shape)] = 0
>>> arr
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```