# Apply function to each cell in DataFrame in place in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to apply function to each cell in a DataFrame *in place* in pandas?

I'm aware of [pandas.DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) but it doesn't seem to allow in place application:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'), 
                     index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
print(frame)
format = lambda x: '%.2f' % x
frame = frame.applymap(format)
print(frame)
```

returns:

```
               b         d         e
Utah    1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172
Ohio   -1.072969  0.865408 -2.301539
Texas   1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039
Oregon -0.249370  1.462108 -2.060141

            b      d      e
Utah     1.62  -0.61  -0.53
Ohio    -1.07   0.87  -2.30
Texas    1.74  -0.76   0.32
Oregon  -0.25   1.46  -2.06
```

`frame = frame.applymap(format)` will temporarily hold 2 copies of `frame` in 
memory, which I don't want.

I know one can apply a function to each cell in place with a NumPy array: [Mapping a NumPy array in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6824122/395857).

Comment: is this putting you over a memory limit? would you consider chunking the data into smaller groups and applying over those?

Comment: @Alter yes memory limit issue. I guess chunking is the plan B :)

Comment: That happens a lot to me as well, and I'm currently using `Dask` for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If my understanding is correct, pandas inplace operations involve calling an `.update_inplace()` method, so for example, `.replace()` would compute the new, replaced data first, then update the dataframe accordingly.

`.applymap()` is a wrapper of `.apply()`; neither of these come with inplace options, but even if they did, they would still need to store all the output data in memory before modifying the dataframe.

From the source, `.applymap()` calls `.apply()`, which calls `.aggregate()`, which calls `_aggregate()`, which calls `._agg()`, which is nothing more than a for loop run in Python <s>(i.e. not Cython -- I think)</s>.

<s>You could of course, modify the underlying NumPy array directly: the following code rounds the dataframe in place:</s>

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100))

for i in frame.index:
    for j in frame.columns:
        val = round(frame.values[i,j])
        frame.values[i,j] = val

newvals = np.zeros(frame.shape[1])
for i in frame.index:
    for j in frame.columns:
        val = round(frame.values[i,j])
        newvals[j] = val
    frame.values[i] = newvals
```

The first method sets one element at a time, and takes about 1s, the second sets by row, and takes 100ms; `.applymap(round)` does it in 20ms.

However, interestingly, if we use `frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 10000))`, both the first method and `.applymap(round)` take about 1.2s, and the second takes about 100ms.

Finally, `frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000,1))` has the first and second method taking 1s (unsurprisingly), and `.applymap(round)` takes 10ms.

These results more or less show that `.applymap` is essentially iterating over each column.

I tried running `frame.applymap(round)` with 3 different shapes: (10000,1), (100,100), and (1,10000). The first was fastest, and the third was slowest; this shows that `.applymap()` iterates over columns. The following code does roughly the same thing as `.applymap()`, in place:

```
newvals = np.zeros(frame.shape[1])
for i in frame.index:
    for j in frame.columns:
        val = round(frame.values[i,j])
        newvals[j] = val
    frame.values[i] = newvals
```

This one works with a copy of the underlying NumPy array:

```
newvals = np.zeros(frame.shape[1])
arr = frame.values
for i in frame.index:
    for j in frame.columns:
        val = round(arr[i,j])
        newvals[j] = val
        arr[i] = newvals
```

With a 100x100 dataframe, the former took about 300ms for me to run, and the latter 60ms -- the difference is solely due to having to access `.values` in the dataframe!

Running the latter in Cython takes about 34ms, whereas `.applymap(round)` does it in 24ms. I have no idea why `.applymap()` is still faster here though.

To answer the question: there probably isn't an in-place implementation of `.applymap()`; if there was, it would most likely involve storing all the 'applied' values before making the in-place change.

If you want to do an `.applymap()` in-place, you could just iterate over the underlying NumPy array. However, this comes at a cost of performance -- the best solution is likely to iterate over the rows or columns: e.g. assign `arr=df.values[i]`, apply the function on each element of `arr`, modify the dataframe by `df.values[i] = arr`, and iterating over all `i`.

Answer (score 2):

If it matters a lot to you, you can try making your own cpython function

I found the [applymap function in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L4410-L4453)

```
def applymap(self, func):
      # ...
      def infer(x):
            if x.empty:
                return lib.map_infer(x, func)
            return lib.map_infer(x.asobject, func)

      return self.apply(infer)
```

which shows that `lib.map_infer` is doing the work behind the scenes

`lib.map_infer` is a cython method defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c53d00f1487716cf462ffa1965f6ec676a6c2593/pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx#L1559-L1595), you can clearly see them allocating space for a new result: `result = np.empty(n, dtype=object)`, found below

```
def map_infer(ndarray arr, object f, bint convert=1):
    """
    Substitute for np.vectorize with pandas-friendly dtype inference
    Parameters
    ----------
    arr : ndarray
    f : function
    Returns
    -------
    mapped : ndarray
    """
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, n
        ndarray[object] result
        object val

    n = len(arr)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype=object)
    for i in range(n):
        val = f(util.get_value_at(arr, i))

        # unbox 0-dim arrays, GH #690
        if is_array(val) and PyArray_NDIM(val) == 0:
            # is there a faster way to unbox?
            val = val.item()

        result[i] = val

    if convert:
        return maybe_convert_objects(result,
                                     try_float=0,
                                     convert_datetime=0,
                                     convert_timedelta=0)

return result
```

... and this is the cliff hangar to my answer. Perhaps the op or someone can modify the cython method to create an inplace version that modifies the original array instead of the creating a new result

-I'm currently away from my coding computer so I can't test anything :(